# How do I test the content of a generated RTF document created using the RTF Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rtf

I am trying to test the content of a document created using the [RTF Ruby Gem](https://github.com/clbustos/rtf) and can't figure out how to extract the actual content from the document.

The method I wish to test

```
class Writer
  def document
    d = RTF::Document.new(RTF::Font.new(RTF::Font::ROMAN, 'Times New Roman'))
    d.paragraph << "blah blah some text"
    d
  end
end
```

The test

```
describe Writer do
  let(:doc) { Writer.new }
  it "should contain 'blah'" do
    doc.should match "blah"
  end
end
```

But an `RTF::Document` does not have a `match` method or a `to_s` method.

How do I interrogate the raw contents of the RTF document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `to_rtf` method as follows

```
doc.to_rtf.should match "blah"
```